# подскажите как загружать фото из галереи в UIImageView в xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

В Storyboard есть компонент UIImageView *myImageView; к которому я хочу подгрузить картинку из галереи, но почему то не получаеться, открывается меню с картинками, выбираю картинку и мой myImageView её не отображает.
Могли бы вы подсказать ещё как сохранять обратно в галерею.

Вот код:

```
- (IBAction)pushBtnLoad:(id)sender
{
    NSLog (@"pressed Btn Load");

    UIImagePickerController *pickerC = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    pickerC.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:pickerC animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    UIImage *gotImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.myImageView.image = gotImage;
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: а объект в interface builder точно указывает на myImageView? можете поставить брейкпоинт и убедиться, что gotImage и myImageView не nil?

Comment: код рабочий, просто я не подключил UIImageView - подключил и всё заработало.

Answer (score 1):

```
(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    UIImage *gotImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.myImageView.image = gotImage;
}
```

Comment: Используйте клавишу `{}` или отступы в четыре пробела для оформления много строчного кода.